# Selenium and websocket

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, jakarta-ee, websocket

I have a javaEE applcation server and I want to run selenium starter.
So I wanted to first log in my application with this little script:

```
public class SeleniumTestKheops {
static WebDriver driver;
static Wait<WebDriver> wait;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);


    final String url = "https://localhost:8444/myApp/";

    driver.navigate().to(url);

    try {
        System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());

        driver.findElement(By.id("11_input")).sendKeys("login");
        driver.findElement(By.id("14_input")).sendKeys("password");


        driver.wait(30000);
    } finally {
        driver.close();
    }
  }
}
```

But it's not working because the Selenium script do not find the `id 11_input`.
To check what the script is seeing I printed the code of the page with :

```
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

And there is no `id 11_input`. The things is I have different result of the page when I display it with Ctrl + u or when I use the console too with F12.
For the login form the code source page is :

```
<div id="main" class="container-fluid" role="main">

    </div>

    <form hidden name="formLogin" method="POST" action="/kheops/">
        <input type="hidden" name="home" value="true">
    </form>



    <form hidden name="formLogout" method="POST" action="/kheops/">
        <input type="hidden" name="home" value="false">
    </form>
```

But when i use the firefox console i have :

```
<div id="36"><div class="form-group ">
<div>
<input class="form-control" id="36_input" placeholder="" 
value="" onfocus="send(36,3214324915873);" onclick="event.stopPropagation();" 
onkeypress="KIEnter(36, event, this, 3214324941411);" 
onblur="KIBlur(36, event, this, 3214324938106);" 
type="text">
```

```
<div id="39">
<div class="form-group ">
<input class="form-control" id="39_input" placeholder="" value="" 
onfocus="send(39,3214325172158);" 
onblur="KIBlur(39, event, this, 3214325191988);" 
onkeypress="KIEnter(39, event, this, 3214325195293);" type="password">
</div>
</div>
```

My colleague told me the source code page was dynamically generated by a websocket. So i guess (but I'm not sure) that the websocket is the problem.
I'm new to websocket and Selenium.
I don't anderstand why the second code is not displayed when i display the source code of the page.
Is there somethings i have to do in my scripts to access the field of the form, like a parameters in my driver that will work in my websocket ?

Any help would be welcome.